# Width turns out too much

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, width, percentage

I'm trying to build some kind of menu that overlaps when called upon (by pressing the menu button).
Since this will be a mobile app I want all measures to be responsive and thus written in percentage instead of pixels.

I'm in some way trying to make a slide in menu like the Facebook App has.

My solution to this is to have a side menu that is 0% width. When the menu-button is pressed the menu will expand to 70% of the device's screen width, thus covering 70% of the width.

I've been trying to get it right by doing this

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[           
  protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {

    trace( stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight );             
    trace(meny.width);

    if (meny.width !== 0) {
      meny.width = 0;
    } else {
      meny.width = 0.5*stage.fullScreenWidth;
    }
  }         
]]> 
</fx:Script>
```

When I debug the trace's show's me the correct values. In this case emulating iPhone 4 it gives me: 540 (width) 960 (height) and 270 (meny.width).

However, even tho the calculation has been correct (270 is 50% of 540) the width of the meny will cover more than half of the screen, approximately 80%~

Why is it doing this and what's the solution? The debugging console is giving me the correct values but it isn't turning out to work.
I also tried on an Android device plugged in and the same issue, so it's not the emulation being a problem.

Any solutions appreciated.

Comment: are you setting scaleX/Y on any of the parent objects?   is your stage.scaleMode set to NO_SCALE?

Comment: I haven't used any scaleX/Y nor 'NO_SCALE:String = "noScale"'. I'm very new to AS3, started last week, so I'm not that experienced. Any user-friendly advice would be a good start point. Thanks

Comment: try setting:  `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;` in your constructor

Comment: I'm sorry but doe to my very limited knowledge of AS3 I don't know what you are referring to. If you could in some way make it a little easier for someone new to understand or perhaps show me what the code would look like I would be forever thankful. I could then also share the solution with my whole class :)

Comment: @nikko The constructor method is the function in your main (document) class that is named after the class itself i.e. if your class file is called "myClass" then a constructor function will also be present, aptly called "myClass". It is the function 'events' "spawn" from within that class

Comment: @adaam he's using Flex, where you don't need to set `StageScaleMode` (I'm guessing it's done for you in Flex's `Application` class).

Comment: Are you setting an `applicationDPI` in your Application class? If so, you need to account for DPI changes in your manually set code (the iPhone runs on 320dpi, by default applicationDPI is set to 160).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use sizes of application's width instead of stage width:
`menu.width=parentApplication.width`

You don't need to deal with stage sizes until you add some global event listeners or use something like `StageWebView` or `StageVideo`

You can read this [articale about mobile apps auto scaling](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/DPI%20Auto%20Scaling%20for%20Density%20Independent%20Mobile%20Apps/) for more details.